# Can't make a DataFrame from Series.groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot turn Series to DataFrame. Tried different functions(pd.DataFrame(columns), pd.to_frame() etc.)

```
depart = employees.groupby('id')['department']
depart_df = depart.to_frame().reset_index()
#employees is a DataFrame
```

It throws an error: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_frame'.

Comment: You are supposed to perform an operation after `groupby`. Should it count the occurences, take the mean etc, `groupby` by itself doesn't return a dataframe

Comment: Extending on what Nuri has said, ```groupby``` needs to know how to combine the data in the other columns when joining rows together which is why cant be used alone. If you check ```type()``` you will see the difference in what is returned.

Comment: Why don't you make your question more specific to what it is you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am trying to just make a DataFrame from the series returned by groupby function